# How can I upload multiple images in python using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to use multiple images using pygame for a character animation. I have 9 images that are all .png and are in the same folder as my code. I also need to upload a background image. My code looks like this, but I did only use 2 of the images for the example instead of all nine of them.

```py
walk right = [pygame.image.load('r1.png'), pygame.image.load('r2.png')

bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that

```
walk_right = [pygame.image.load('r1.png'), pygame.image.load('r2.png')...]
```

to make it a bit tidier, you can use a loop

```
walk_right = []
for i in range(9):
    image = pygame.image.load("r" + str(i) + ".png")
    walk_right.append(image)
```

or to do the loop in one line

```
walk_right = [pygame.image.load("r" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(9)]
```

---

The directory can be any, the above example is if the images are in the same folder, if the images are in another folder inside game files you can do

```
"Images/r" + str(i) + ".png"
```

Or get the whole directory to the images

```
Dir = "C:/Users/user/Documents/GameFiles/Images/"
pygame.image.load(Dir + "r" + str(i) + ".png")
```

If its still not right, make sure everything is spelt the same, do the images start at 0 or 1, the above example starts at 0.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. What directory should my images be in? I have them in a folder meant for the project, along with the file that my code is in.

Comment: Okay I will try this. I have changed them to start at 0

Comment: No it didn't. I feel like I always have trouble with loading images because I've never done it. Thank you for trying to help me. I dont have anyone else to ask help to because I don't know anyone else who knows Python well.

Comment: @l1359082 Allgood, Post a picture of folder where the script is and where the images are, and mabye all of your code.